# Checking docker swarm container status in node js

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-swarm

Is there any way using which I can determine if the container is still up and running using container id in node js? I have three server setup with docker swarm and containers are distributed to all three. At the start of the process I will save every container id in job it is executing in DB and later, want to check if those containers are still up and running one by one and update the jobs if any of the containers are down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use healthcheck points in docker, when running in swarm mode docker will restart the containers if the healthcheck endpoint fails.

Comment: I want to check for an individual containers

Comment: healthcheck endpoints can be applied to single containers.